# How can my class-validator validate union string | number?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, class-validator

I have an simple DTO class for validation

```js
class SearchIssuerDto {
    search: string | number;
}
```

What is the correct way to validate the search param that it can accept an string or a number ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom validator for that:

```
@ValidatorConstraint({ name: 'string-or-number', async: false })
export class IsNumberOrString implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  validate(text: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
    return typeof text === 'number' || typeof text === 'string';
  }

  defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments) {
    return '($value) must be number or string';
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
class SearchIssuerDto {
  @IsDefined()
  @Validate(IsNumberOrString)
  search: number | string;
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible to do it without custom validator, but if it's impossible thanks mate

Comment: I looked around for other solution, but sadly did not find anything else